# Makefiles and understanding wildcards

Tags: makefile

So I'm trying to start using make on an existing project and I'm getting super confused as to how to properly use wildcards. or atleast that's what I think I need.
basically this is the command I'm trying to run `fieldalignment ./**/*copy`. copy would be a variable that would be passed into the command and basically I'm just trying to search the whole current directory and the subdirectories for that package and run the `fieldalignment` command against it. I'm working in go. from what I understand the '*' should be replace with wildcards? but I'm not entirely sure how.

this is the basic idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
checkfieldalignment: 
    fieldalignment ./...$(PACK)
fixfieldalignment : 
    fieldalignment -fix ./**/*$(PACK)
```

The first one kind of works but also gets an error 3. not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make implements standard POSIX-style globbing in its `wildcard` function, the same as the traditional shell globbing and the default globbing in shells like bash.  And, when make invokes a shell to run a recipe it always invokes `/bin/sh`, not whatever shell the user happens to be running.

Make does not implement "extended" globbing such as that provided by zsh and some other shells, or available in bash if you turn it on.

And `/bin/sh` is a POSIX shell, or a link to another shell that is running in "POSIX mode", so it doesn't support extended globbing either.

So, special features like `**` to mean "search all subdirectories" are not available here.

You can use the `find` program to replace it, like this:

```
fixfieldalignment : 
        fieldalignment -fix $$(find ./ -name '*$(PACK)')
```